# Is it possible to return two values from findGrade()?

Tags: java

The score is increasing until 40 using the `increaseScore()` method.

If a boolean `flag` is `true`, the score will be reduced by 10 (so, in this case, it will be 30), and display score = 30 and grade = D in `toString()`.

But I only can get score = 40 and grade = D in `toString()`.

Is it possible to add `return score;` after `score = score - 10;` in `findGrade()`?

```
public int increaseScore(){
   score = score + 10;
   return score;
    }

public char findGrade(){
    if (flag)
        score = score - 10;

    char grade = 'A';

    if (80<=score)
        grade = 'A';
    else if (60<=score && score <= 79)
        grade = 'B';
    else if (40<=score && score <= 69)
        grade = 'C';
    else 
        grade ='D';

    return grade;
}

public String toString(){
    return teamName + " " + score + " " + findGrade();
}
```

Comment: Without getting into detail about what you are trying to do, simply put, a java method can only return a single item. (Note that you can return an array or something that in itself contains multiple items)

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish.  `score` is declared as a field (well, I *hope* it is, since it's not declared anywhere else), so you don't really need to worry about returning multiple values from `findGrade()`.  You already have access to the field, and you're using it in `toString()`.  If you could provide more clarification as to why you think you need two return values, perhaps one of us could answer your question better?  Perhaps it isn't a raw duplicate of returning two things from a function?

Comment: if you want to return more than one value, Put them in an Array and return the array

Comment: I've started up a meta discussion on this post; [you can find it here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252653/1079354)  I believe that it's actually an XY problem; there's a better way to solve this issue as opposed to returning two values.

Comment: You need to make sure that `findGrade` gets called before `toString` uses `score`.  Perhaps `public String toString(){ char grade = findGrade(); return teamName + " " + score + " " + grade; }`

Answer (score 1):

you can add another method for `toString()` use:

```
public String findGradeString() {
    return score + ":" + findGrade();
}
public String toString(){
    return teamName + " " + score + " " + findGradeString();
}
```

Comment: This continues to read `score` before the call to `findGrade()`, so it doesn't solve the problem.